# Concave function - proof

Tags: functions, proof-writing, convex-analysis

Is there any analytical (if numerical it is obvious) way to prove that:

$$f(x) < 2f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

where $f(x)$ is any concave function?

Comment: For $f(x) = -1 - x^2$, $f(1) > 2f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the concave function we obtain
$$\frac{f\left(0\right)+f(x)}{2}\leq f\left(\frac{0+x}{2}\right).$$
Thus, for your inequality we need something like $f(0)>0.$

Answer (score 0):

Take $f : x \mapsto \ln(x)$, $f$ is concave.
For $x=1$

$$
\ln\left(1\right)=0 \text{ and }2\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-2\ln\left(2\right)
$$
You dont have
$$
0<-2\ln\left(2\right)
$$